# Python Request response time timeouts

Tags: python, time, python-requests, response-time

I am trying to perform some benchmarking and having some issues with Request. The problem is that if the response time is high it throws some errors. How can I make it return the `else` if  the `request.get` waits more than for instance 2 seconds.

```
time = requests.get('http://www.google.com').elapsed.total_seconds()

if time < 1:
    print "Low response time"
else:
    print "High reponse time"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timeout parameter of `requests.get`. `requests.get` will raise `requests.exceptions.Timeout` exception if request took more time than timeout value.

```
try:
    resp = requests.get('http://www.google.com', timeout=1.0)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print "High reponse time"
else:
    print "Low response time"
```

Comment: That works, but you have to change between high and low.

Comment: If exception is generated then it means response time was high (more than 1.0), so I think it is right? `else` part will be executed if request completed with in timeout time hence Low response time.

Comment: Becuase it is throwing "high respone time" when it takes less than 1 seconds and low response time when it takes more than 1 seconds.

Comment: @user3580316 are you sure you are using exact same code? For me here is the result of printing time taken by request and print output. `0.227112,
Low response time`

Comment: You can test by replacing `resp = requests.get('http://www.google.com', timeout=1.0)` with `print requests.get('http://www.google.com', timeout=1.0).elapsed.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what errors are called (do you mean exceptions here?). If it throws exceptions, then you could put it in a try / except:

```
try:
    time = requests.get('http://www.google.com').elapsed.total_seconds()
    if time < 1:
        print "Low response time"
    else:
        print "High response time"
except:
    # threw an exception
    print "High response time"
```

If you know the type of exception thrown, then I would set except to catch that exception and no others.

Comment: How can I make it go the `except` if the reponse takes longer than 2 seconds? Since I dont want to wait the uneccary 20 seconds (if the reponse time is 20 seconds). If it takes more than 2 seconds, I want it to stop immeditly and go the `except`